# Building json dynamically

Tags: apex, json, map, dynamic, custom-metadata

Following on from [Any Ideas for Building dynamic JSON with apex.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347898/any-ideas-for-building-dynamic-json-with-apex)  Trying to build json literal from an sObject dynamically (according to custom metadata - see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347898/any-ideas-for-building-dynamic-json-with-apex) for more detais)
I have allowed `Json_field__c` to be a path as [@PhilW](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50252/phil-w)  said e.g. *item.items.item.extetnalId*. for the externalId in the following Json output:

```
   {
    "entity": { "externalId": "{{customerExternalId}}" },
    "item": {
        "items": [{
            "item": { "externalId": "{{itemExternalId}}" },
            "rate": 60
         }]
     }
   }
```

In first the code builds the new value from end to start in a regressive list of `Map<String,Object>` e.g.
`rightSideMapsList[0] =` {externalId = value}
`rightSideMapsList[1] =` {item = {externalId = value}}
e.t.c

(for array including it in a List<Map<String,Object>> then turning it to be an object in next Map<String,Object>).

In second i check if the first key(most outer "item") exists
(if not found i add `rightSideMapsList[rightSideMapsList.size()-1]` to the`resultMap`Map<String,Object>) if does exists i remove that key from result Map and iterating up until by casting objects to `Map<String,Object>` until Reaching non existing key preserving values in a List of map<string,object>.

my problem was what do i do with an array of objects how can i identify to which object i should add the new key value pair? e.g. if i had another pair of `{ "item : {}}, "rate" : 90 }` and i need to add `"stage : "close won"`..